# Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно оформить предложение? Знаки препинания

Tags: пунктуация

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильнее написать?

За большим окном медленно осыпалась с дерева пожелтевшая листва, ложась плотным ковром на землю. Осень… Ей нравилась осень. Нравился тот неповторимый запах, вызывающий лёгкую ностальгию, нравилось, как шуршит под ногами листва, а особенно нравилось сидеть в тёплом помещении кафетерия и, держа в руке чашку с горячим кофе, наблюдать, как за окном расцветает яркими красками осень.

Или же:

За большим окном медленно осыпалась с дерева пожелтевшая листва, ложась плотным ковром на землю. Осень… Ей нравилась осень: нравился тот неповторимый запах, вызывающий лёгкую ностальгию; нравилось, как шуршит под ногами листва; а особенно нравилось сидеть в тёплом помещении кафетерия и, держа в руке чашку с горячим кофе, наблюдать, как за окном расцветает яркими красками осень.

Я буду очень благодарна, если вы сможете помочь мне в этом вопросе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, точки с запятой категорически не нужны - они были бы уместны при более пространных придаточных, чем-нибудь эдаким осложнённых, со своими запятыми.

У нас всего два предложения с "нравился/ось", и перед "а особенно" знак **;** просто режет глаз.

И ещё немножко вкусовщинки: убрать из лирического текста производственное слово "помещение".

Ага, исчо место для придирки нашла: "Ей нравилась осень" и в этом же предложении  - "нравилось наблюдать, как за окном расцветает осень".

И - расцветает ли? Может, что-нибудь *расцвечивает?* яркими красками?

Comment: Получилось, что я начала с непонятного "нет", а это "нет" было ответом на комментарий Артёма к вопросу, что оба варианта хороши и имеют право на жизнь.

Comment: Галина, между однородными членами двоеточие не ставится. И что вам мешает поставить точку с запятой перед союзом а, если предложение достаточно распространено, внутри него есть уже запятые?!

Comment: И правда, без слова "помещение" намного лучше. Спасибо.

Comment: Сержик, я нигде не предлагаю двоеточий, обсуждается только то, что на взгляд отвечающего требует правки.  Категорически против знака "тэзэ" (так полиграфисты называют точку с запятой) перед "а особенно", правила не знаю, практик мы. Руководствуюсь (при имхо ненужности знака): а что ему там делать = а что он там забыл. Обычно не ошибаюсь - у меня стажу работы с текстами 35 лет.

Comment: Галина, по поводу точки с запятой, я рекомендовал ее ставить на основании правил. Ошибиться могут все, и редакторы. А как вы работали, не зная правил? Не в обиду будет сказано. Удивился, поэтому спрашиваю.

Comment: Да пожалуйста, отвечу. Практикой знания нарабатываются: моему чисто редакторскому опыту предшествовал многолетний корректорский. Вот диалог в корректорской: "Да как же без запятых, они ж интонационные!" - "А чего их плодить-то". И это была лучшая корректорская на комбинате "Московская правда".

Comment: Я не понимаю, какие и зачем правила; я уже стала единым целым с языком.

Answer (score 2):

Почти целиком присоединяюсь к мнению Галины.
Двоеточие допустимо, точки с запятой не нужны. "Помещение" лучше убрать.
А вот многочисленные "нравилось" мне ухо не режут. И глаз не режут.

Comment: Спасибо за поддержку, друг! А я не жаловалась на изобилие "нравилось", напротив, я сказала, что таких предложений всего два, потому и тэзэ не нужно.

Answer (score 1):

Первый вариант корректный. Двоеточие ставится перед перечислением, если есть обобщающее слово, или после предложения, заключающие в себе разъяснение или раскрытие содержания того, о чём говорится в первом предложении. В вашем тексте эти условия не выполняются. Точку с запятой можно поставить только перед союзом ***а,*** т.к.связываемые им предложения значительно распространены и имеют внутри себя запятые.

Comment: Спасибо, что помогли определиться с вариантом текста. Теперь я знаю, какой оставить.